# Matlab normxcorr for 1D signals

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I am very surprised not to find a version of normxcorr2 for 1D signals in Matlab ! I implemented something like that by hand (with 2 for loops, and normalizing the template as well as the window under the template (in the 1D signal in which the template is searched).

Did I just not find it or does it not exist? (A normalized cross correlation (NCC) for 1D signals, i.e., like normxcorr2 but for vectors)

(cf. https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html for the 2D version )

e.g.:

```
template=[1 2 3]

signal=[0 1 4 8 9 3 7 7 1 2 3 0 5 5 0]
```

the NCC should find the max at a lag of 9 (because you can see that the pattern [1 2 3] starts at pos 9). I consider here sliding the template starting at the template positioned over the window [0 1 4] of the signal and finishes at [5 5 0] , like that I obtain an output signal of length:

```
 outputLen=length(signal)-length(template)+1.
```

P.S. and it seems clearly that corr or xcorr does not do the same thing even with the 'normalization' argument because what I am looking for is something that normalized the kernel and the window in the signal at each step, which is quite cumbersome but needed for the NCC as mentioned in : http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture07.pdf for example)

Comment: Is the option *coeff* to function *xcorr()* doing what you want? or what about the function *corrcoef()* ?

Comment: @Fat32 thanks for your answer! No these functions are not the ones I m looking for since i m really looking for the cross-correlation between a template (by definition a smaller signal) with a longer signal

Comment: corrcoef and xcorr with 'coef' or 'normalization' require to have both signal of same size

Comment: what do you think? It seems strange not to have the equivalent of normxcorr2 for 1D signals ?!

Comment: I updated my question to be more precise; it is a 1D template matching problem by Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC).

Comment: @Fat32 I hope it is better explained now.

Comment: if you're looking for a cross correlation between a template and a signal, then the function *xcorr* is computing a crude estimate of it by actually computing a **convolution** between a reversed template and the signal. This is also similar to a *matched filtering*. And afaik they work as expected. It seems you want a strict *tamplate matching*, because otherwise it cannot indicate the lag 9 as a match, because the signal and the template are more correlated more than you think. Can you show your hand implemented code as how you compute the NCC and find the lag to be at 9th sample ?